# Django, changing form field based on form.instance in admin

Tags: python, django, forms, admin

I have an admin page that uses inlines. I would like to change a field in the inline form depending on the state of the parent model on the page. Is there a way to check for this in the inline form object?

I have a few models that depend on each other. For the sake of fewer clicks, I'd like to be able to create them all at once, but then introduce some user friendly features once database entries exist (i.e., `ChoiceField` instead of `IntegerField` for setting `Element().quality`.

```
#proj/elements/models.py
...
class Group(models.Model):
    """A group of elements"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class QualityChoice(models.Model):
    """Translates quality values to human-readable descriptions
    within a group"""
    value = models.SmallIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('value', 'group')

class Element(models.Model):
    """An element"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quality = models.SmallIntegerField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
#proj/elements/admin.py
...
class ElementForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Element
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'quality', 'group', 'marker_id')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(ElementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         if self.instance.group:
              # Set quality field to be a select scoped to valid choices
              # for the group.  Assume `choices` is set elsewhere
              self.fields['quality'] = ChoiceField(choices=choices)

class ElementInline(TabularInline):
    model = Element
    form = ElementForm
    extra = 0
    exclude = ('marker_id',)

class QualityInline(TabularInline):
    model = QualityChoice
    extra = 0

class GroupAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
    list_display_links = ('name',)
    inlines = [QualityChoiceInline, ElementInline,]

...
```

On an **add group** page, the `quality` field should be an `IntegerField` since no `QualityChoice` values have been set for the group. The user just has to manually map the values.

On a **change group** page, the `quality` field should be a `ChoiceField` populated with choices scoped to the current group.

However, the instance doesn't have the `group` set at the time the form is instantiated, so the `ElementForm().fields['quality']` defaults to an `IntegerField`.

Is there any way to pull this off?